# javascript read html comment after closing html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I know you shouldn't put anything after the closing 'html' tag. Tell SharePoint about it...

```html
[...]
</body>
</html><!-- Rendered using cache profile:Public Internet (Purely Anonymous) at: 2013-06-06T12:57:10 -->
```

This is what the SharePoint output caching debug information looks like. I want this hidden comment to be visible on every page. Switching to source view and going to the end of the file makes me tired.

In an effort to not reinvent the wheel I figured it would be the smartest choice to add a piece of javascript code to my masterpage which copies the comment to a location (within the page) of my choosing.

**Any idea on how I get hold of the comment via javascript? jquery is ok.**

Comment: the following link may help <http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1563-jQuery-Comments-Plug-in-To-Access-HTML-Comments-For-DOM-Templating.htm>

Comment: +1 to @mrida but the comment is at the end, after the closing html tag and might be stripped?  Dunno, but, y, if he can get the original source via jquery, then it should be possible to obtain using simple regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `document.lastChild.nodeValue` will do the trick.

(Assuming you run it after the DOM is ready)

### edit

I took the liberty of modifying the code from undefined's answer :)

```
$(function(){
    $('body').append(document.lastChild.nodeValue);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/arodiz/3/edit

Comment: @VitorCanova that is a bummer :/ i can't get it working in IE8 even when trying undefined's jquery solution

Comment: Well, OP only wants to see the comment for debugging purposes, it shouldn't be cross-browser.

Comment: @xec Yep. Hope IE8 die with Windows XP next year.

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I had a working solution too but it was 10 times the code compared to yours :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `nodeValue` of the `Comment` Object and append it to `Body` Element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var comment = $('html').prop('nextSibling').nodeValue;
   $('<div/>').html(comment).appendTo('body');
});
```

http://jsbin.com/arodiz/2/edit

Comment: Weird way to get the next sibling ... :)

Comment: @NULL Interesting. `NULL` talking with `undefined`. ;)